# Is it possible for rsync to read files simulteneosly on source and destination?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm curious how rsync works internally: as I understand, rsync first reads files at source, then calculates checksums for chunks of these files and then sends this data to a remote rsync daemon at destination, which then reads files from a list he has received from source daemon.
So, my question is it possilbe for rsync to ran simultaneously:

- source rsync reads files
- source rsync sends a list of files he has to the destination rsync
- source rsync calculates checksums for chunks
- destination rsync reads files from a list from source rsync
- destination rsync calculates checksums for chunks
- destination rsync compares and asks for chunks which differ from source rsync

In my usage scenario it can speed up sync of large files (50-500GBs), because file readings and checksum calculations will be done in parallel.

Thanks